# Browser-Cache reload with manifest

Tags: javascript, html, caching

We are searching for a nice and clean solution to reload the automatically generated browser cache for a site. Think about an versioned client which need a cache reload if a new client is released.

There are many ways to force a reload:

1. Use HTML5 manifest and "applicationCache"
2. Using a timestamp in javascript "script tag".
3. Server: Different HTML Header with "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"

However, they seem not as nice and clean solutions. We dont want to provide a offline solution with HTMl applicationCache.

**The question is:** Is there a way to use a manifest file (or something else) to give the client a version and if the version changes the browser automatically reloads his cache? Probably with HTML5 applicationCache, but we dont want to use the site offline and store everything. We just want to tell the Browser to clear his generated cache.

If i understand it correctly this is not possible or is a different usage with HTML5 applicationCache. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Is there any chance you could use PHP in your project aswell? You can set an outdated expiration date in PHP and it will refresh automatically

Comment: No we dont use PHP in our project. I am sure we can achieve this by modifying the html header from server but i dont think this should be the way.

Answer (score 1):

One common approach is to:

1. Have the main HTML file (for instance, `index.html`) served with `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate` and `maxage` and such (basically, don't let it be cached)
2. Use version numbers in the names of the resources it loads, for instance `script-v6.js` and then `script-v7.js` when it changes, serving those resources with far-future headers so that they can be cached for a long time
3. Obviously in development, we just have simple filenames; the version number is added by the build process that does all the other build things like minification, combining files, etc.